# Create template, DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to create a template using the following code:

```
def create_template(token):
    docusign_account_id = getenv("DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID")
    document_base64 = getenv("DOCUMENT_BASE64")

    post_params = {'account_id': docusign_account_id}
    post_headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': token}

    payload = {'documentBase64': document_base64, 'emailSubject': "Create template test", 'name': "Test"}
    post_r = requests.post(url="https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/b24dee2d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-d9d81de867ab/templates", params=post_params, headers=post_headers, data=json.dumps(payload))

    post_r.raise_for_status()
```

By executing this code, I am creating a new template in my docusign account. But the document I have attached in base64 is nowhere to be found.

Any suggestions are more than welcome,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocuSign is expecting an array of documents (can be one or more) like so:

```
payload = {'documents':
          [{"documentBase64": document_base64,
          "documentId": "1", "fileExtension": "pdf",
          "name": "Lorem Ipsum"}], 'emailSubject': "Create template test", 
          'name':"Test"}
```